# When i try to do apt update with repos https://ftp.ustclug.org/~zsj/anbox stretch Release it shows an error:its has no release file

Tags: kali-linux, repository

I wrote the command: `apt update` with repository : https://ftp.ustclug.org/~zsj/anbox stretch Release' in kali linux amd64 2017.2 and it shows ther error:
E: The repository 'https://ftp.ustclug.org/~zsj/anbox stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the stretch repository from your sources.list.

You should have only the following line in your [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://www.kali.org/docs//general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

you can use:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```